# How to prove that $\mathrm{Proj}\left(B/J\right)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Proj}\left(A/J\right)$ if $I\subset J$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $B$ be a graded ring with positive degrees, and let $I$ and $J$ be homogeneous ideals of $B$. We suppose that there exists $N$ such that $I\cap B_{n}=J\cap B_{n}$ for all $n\ge N$.

How to show that if $I\subset J$, the natural arrow $\mathrm{Proj}\left(B/J\right)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Proj}\left(B/I\right)
 $ is an isomorphism?

Comment: You mean to write $I \cap B_n = J \cap B_n$. Check equality on the distinguished affine open sets $D(f) = \operatorname{Spec} B_{(f)}$.

Comment: See *Algebraic Geometry* by R. Hartshorne, Chapter II, Ex. 2.14 (c).

Comment: @Hoot Would you please write about this in more detail in an answer? The textbook also says about checking equality on the distinguished affine open sets, but I don't think I've seen an example of that being done.

Comment: @Jake Sure. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The morphism in question comes from the surjection $B/I \to B/J$. If $f \in B$ is homogeneous of positive degree then we get $(B/I)_f \to (B/J)_f$ and then $((B/I)_f)_0 \to ((B/J)_f)_0$, both surjective. So the only question is injectivity. Say $b/f^n$ maps to $0$ where $b \in B_{n \deg f}$ (everything should be mod $I$, really). Then for $m \gg 0$ we have $f^mb \equiv 0 \bmod{J}$, so $f^mb \in J_{(n+m)\deg f}$ and for $m$ large enough the hypothesis tells you that this is the same as $I_{(n+m)\deg f}$ and it follows that $b/f^n$ is already zero in $((B/I)_f)_0$.